# Does Excel/VBA optimize redundant variables away?

Tags: excel, vba, jit

I have a pretty time consuming Excel macro, with a lot of input data. First, i load these data into an array (arr).

Is this code

```
for n =1 to 1000000
...
arr(n,1)=arr(n,2)+arr(n,4)*arr(n,78) 
...
next n
```

faster than this

```
for n =1 to 1000000
...
Sensor_Top=arr(n,2)
Age       =arr(n,4)
Material  =arr(n,78)
output    =Sensor_Top+Age*Material
arr(n,1)  =output
...
next n
```

?

So in other words, i would like to include unnecessary variable declarations for readability. Does VBA do some sort of JIT compiling to deal with this?

Comment: Assuming `arr` came from a worksheet, why wouldn't `arr(n, 1)` be precomputed on the Excel worksheet in the first place? Why write any code to do a calculation whose result you can readily grab along with the rest of the data?

Comment: It does not. This was probably unclear in this toy example. In reality the calculations are a lot more involved. (I load the input data into an array, and then populate a different output array with the results. As last step i copy the output array back into the worksheet.)

Comment: Consider putting your *actual code* up for peer review on [codereview.se] if you're interested in feedback on any/all aspects of the code, including (but not limited to) performance.

Comment: "Is this code […] faster than this […]?" - did you run it and try it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These helper variables will have negligible effect on the the performance.  Using an enumeration would be more efficient.

```
Public Enum NamedArrayColumns
    output = 1
    Sensor_Top = 2
    Age = 4
    Material = 78
End Enum

Sub Foo()
    Rem Some Code

    For n = 1 To 1000000
        arr(n, output) = arr(n, Sensor_Top) + arr(n, Age) * arr(n, Material)
    Next n

End Sub
```

Answer (score 4):

Not that I know of, but then again it's not like VBA to P-Code compilation is so completely documented that this kind of thing is easy to see.

I doubt the compiler does any inlining or other kind of optimization, but I could be wrong (VB6 *did* have optimization settings that did... *something*).

That said, write code for readability and maintainability.

If your code is too slow, the bottleneck isn't going to be what variables you're using.

As for whether A is faster than B... you have two horses - race them!

Answer (score 3):

If you want to improve readability then this can also work:

```
const c_sensor_top as long = 2
const c_age as long = 4
const c_output as long = 78

for n = 1 to 1000000
    ...
    arr(n,1) = arr(n, c_sensor_top) + arr(n, c_age) * arr(n, c_output) 
    ...
next n
```